# OpenLayers dynamically label polygon segments

Tags: openlayers-2, labeling

My requirement is to show dynamic label on polygon feature's segments with some offset. The label text should have the rank of each segment. If it is a square which starts at top left corner it will look as

```
     1    
  -------
  |      |
 4|      |2
  |      |
  --------
     3
```

Can anyone give me some pointers in achieving this using OpenLayers?

Comment: What do you mean by the rank of each segment?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know you can only have one label per feature. So you'll probably need to generate 4 lines from `feature.geometry.getVertices()` with individual labels and their offsets.

Or generate an invisible points between each location of `feature.geometry.getVertices()` with individual labels and their offsets.